# How to refresh the outlook add in taskpane after redirect to the taskpane page

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have created outlook web add-in. In this add-in i have implemented salesforce login using jsforce. After the login its redirect to taskpane. But the taskpane is not rendered again. How to refresh the taskpane and re-render the taskpane UI ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a new `locaion` or use the [Location: reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) method. The `Location.reload()` method reloads the current URL, like the Refresh button.